# Can't start postgres server, SHMMAX too small

Tags: postgresql, configuration

When I try to start the postgres server with `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start` I get this error:

> Starting PostgreSQL 8.4 database server: mainThe PostgreSQL server
>   failed to start. Please check the log output: 2012-10-31 17:52:46 EDT
>   FATAL: could not create shared memory segment: Invalid argument
>   2012-10-31 17:52:46 EDT DETAIL: Failed system call was
>   shmget(key=5432001, size=188080128, 03600). 2012-10-31 17:52:46 EDT
>   HINT: This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared
>   memory segment exceeded your kernel's SHMMAX parameter. You can either
>   reduce the request size or reconfigure the kernel with larger SHMMAX.
>   To reduce the request size (currently 188080128 bytes), reduce
>   PostgreSQL's shared_buffers parameter (currently 19200) and/or its
>   max_connections parameter (currently 103). If the request size is
>   already small, it's possible that it is less than your kernel's SHMMIN
>   parameter, in which case raising the request size or reconfiguring
>   SHMMIN is called for. The PostgreSQL documentation contains more
>   information about shared memory configuration. ... failed!

What should I do here?  Shared_buffers is actually set to 150MB and max_connections is actually set to 100 in the only postgresql.conf file available to it...

I don't know if the request is unusually high, SHMMAX unusually low, or if postgres grabbed some config parameters from the Aether, either seem equally likely...

What am I supposed to make of this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Search for the error message, or read it - it explains what to do. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=could+not+create+shared+memory+segment%3A+Invalid+argument+%5Bpostgresql%5D  or http://www.google.com.au/search?q=could+not+create+shared+memory+segment%3A+Invalid+argument&oq=could+not+create+shared+memory+segment%3A+Invalid+argument .

Comment: possible duplicate of [postgresql shared memory settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616935/postgresql-shared-memory-settings)

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked many times. Try a search. Or Google.

[This chapter of the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/kernel-resources.html) deals with it comprehensively.

Comment: Linking to `/current/interactive` may not be ideal here, because shared memory configuration changed considerably in PostgreSQL 9.3 with the switch to anonymous mmap-ed memory instead of system V shm, so this link will cease to apply when 9.3 becomes `/current/`.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Good point. Also, the question is for PostgreSQL 8.4 explicitly. Changed link to 8.4.